# Extracting string from <h1> element with logic attached

Tags: python, html, for-loop, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape some sports game data and I have ran into some issues with my code. Eventually I will move this data into a dataframe and then eventually a database.

I am trying to scrape some sports data.

In the code, I have found the class element of one of the headers I would like to parse. There are multiple h1's in the HTML I am parsing.

```
 <div class="type-game">
      <div class="type">NHL Regular Season</div>
      <h1>Blackhawks vs. Ducks</h1>
 </div>
```

With this HTML structure, how can I get the h1 to return to a string I can use to populate a dataframe?

Code I have tried so far is:

```
 req = requests.get(url) # + str(page) + '/')
 soup = bs(req.text, 'html.parser')

 stype = soup.find('h1', class_ ='type-game')
 print(stype)
```

This code returns "None". I have checked other articles on here and nothing has worked so far.

For the next level of my question, is there a way to create a For loop or similar to go through all of the pages (website is numbered sequentially for events) for any games that contain a string?

For example, if I wanted to only save games that have the Chicago Blackhawks in the h1 for the div element that has class= type-game?

Pseudocode would be something like this:

```
 For webpages 1 to 10000:
      if class_='type-game' 'h1' contains "Blackhawks"
           then proceed with parsing the code
      if not, skip the code and go to the next webpage
```

I know this is a little open ended, but I have a good VBA background and trying to apply those coding ideas to Python has been a challenge.

Comment: can ask what site you are pulling from? There might be an easier, more efficient, more robust way if I can see the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your elements more specific for example with `css selectors`:

```
soup.select('h1:-soup-contains("Blackhawks")')
```

or

```
soup.select('div.type-game h1:-soup-contains("Blackhawks")')
```

To get the text from a tag just use `.text` or `get_text()`

```
for e in soup.select('h1:-soup-contains("Blackhawks")'):
    print(e.text)
```

#### Example

```
html='''
<div class="type-game">
      <div class="type">NHL Regular Season</div>
      <h1>Blackhawks vs. Ducks</h1>
</div>
<div class="type-game">
      <div class="type">NHL Regular Season</div>
      <h1>Hawks vs. Ducks</h1>
</div>
<div class="type-game">
      <div class="type">NHL Regular Season</div>
      <h1>Ducks vs. Blackhawks</h1>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')

for e in soup.select('h1:-soup-contains("Blackhawks")'):
    print(e.text)
```

#### Output

```
Blackhawks vs. Ducks
Ducks vs. Blackhawks
```

### EDIT

```
for e in soup.select('div.type-game h1'):
    if 'Blackhawks' in e:
        pint(e.text)#or do what ever is to do
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, is there any way to get whatever is in the h1 if I do not want to be specific to a team like how I stated it above? Aka capture all games?

Comment: Sure, take a look added an edit  just iterate over `soup.select('div.type-game h1')`  and use `.text`